# Rails Load values on button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller i have :

```
def index 

   @quizzes = Quiz.where(:id => n..n+4)

end
```

In my view I want to load 5 objects at a time and if user click "next" button next 5 objects should be shown like pagination. I don't want to use any pagination gem because I want to add more features when user click "next" button.
I want to increase value of n by 5 each time "next" is clicked.
Please explain

Thanks for your help in advance

EDITED:

I tried this

```
 def next     
     @start = params[:start].to_i||0
     redirect_to Quiz
     return @start     
   end


  def index     
  @start = next
   @quizzes = Quiz.where(:id => @start..@start+4)
     #  @quizzes = Quiz.all
  end
```

In view

```
<%= link_to 'next', next_path(start: @start+5) %>
```

Comment: @Floegipoky I am editing

Comment: error :/home/aditya/GREibt/app/controllers/quizzes_controller.rb:24: void value expression for  @start = next

Comment: what do you want to achieve by `redirect_to Quiz`? `return @start` will never happen because of the redirrect

Comment: @IvanSelivanov its not working even without redirect

Comment: I found the solution the problem is next is reserve keyword. its working if ia m changing name of next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this, I guess:

```
<%= link_to 'next', quizzes_path(start: @start+5), method: :get %>
```

and in controller:

```
def index 

   @start = params[:start].to_i||0
   @quizzes = Quiz.where(:id => @start..@start+4)

end
```

OR, if You want to use `button_to`, you need to add a hidden field:

```
<%= form_tag quizzes_path do%>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'start', @start %>
<%= submit_tag 'next' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: its not working and on button click its giving link wit no params

Comment: it works for me with link_to. maybe for button_to there is a slightly different syntax. Try to replace button_to with link_to. will it work?

Comment: yes its working great help thanks. Can u tell me how i can do it using another method

Comment: What do You mean by 'another method'? `button_to`? I've edited my answer to include `button_to` solution

Comment: why do you use next_path? is it defined in your routes? why not to use index action instead?

Comment: I want to add more feature in "next" method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75425/discussion-between-adt-and-ivanselivanov).